# Python Turtle collision border collision not working

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to get my turtle object to turn 180 degrees when it comes into contact with the border however this doesn't happen. Rather than i want to use and if statement saying if the x and y cor's are higher or lower than a certain amount they will cause the object to move back. Here is the code bellow.

```
from turtle import *
import turtle

title("Pokemon: Fire Red")
t = turtle.Turtle()
screen = t.getscreen()

t.penup()


t.left(90)

border = turtle.Turtle()
border.up()
border.setposition(-240, 160)
border.down()
border.pensize(3)
for side in range(2):
    border.forward(480)
    border.right(90)
    border.forward(320)
    border.right(90)

tx, ty = t.pos()
if tx < -240 or tx > 240 or ty < -160 or ty > 160:
    t.hide()




Screen()

showturtle()



def k1():
    t.forward(50)



def k2():
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(50)

    t.right(90)

def k3():
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(50)

    t.left(90)

def k4():
    t.forward(-50)





onkey(k1, "Up")
onkey(k2, "Left")
onkey(k3, "Right")
onkey(k4, "Down")


listen()
mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate from [Detecting collision in Python turtle game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461566/detecting-collision-in-python-turtle-game?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Have you made a function `hide()` under `class turtle`? I've looked for it but `turtle module` doesn't provide such function. I'll be answering under assumption that your code

```
tx, ty = t.pos()
if tx < -240 or tx > 240 or ty < -160 or ty > 160:
    t.hide()
```

is intended to check the collide. In this code, you are checking the collision with border just once. The performance you expect from this should be called every time turtle moves. That is, under every `k#` functions. So the change would be like this :

```
def collision_check (t):
    tx,ty = t.pos()
    if tx < -240 or tx > 240 or ty < -160 or ty > 160:
        t.right(180)
        t.forward(50)
        t.right(180)

def k1():
    t.forward(50)
    collision_check(t)

def k2():
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(50)
    collision_check(t)
    t.right(90)

def k4():
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(50)
    collision.check(t)
    t.right(180)
```

Same goes with `k3`. k4 was adjusted because this `collision_check` function works upon the turtle's direction.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a unique motion sequence for your turtle that's always biased in the ***up*** direction such that I don't believe generic collision detection logic will work.  I also believe that absolute ***heading*** settings will work better for you than relative `right()` and `left()` turns.  Accordingly, I've reworked your code using headings and ***logo*** mode since it sets ***up*** to be 0 degrees:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 480, 320

def move_turtle(distance, heading):
    ahead = min(50, distance)

    if ahead:
        if heading != yertle.heading():
            yertle.setheading(heading)

        yertle.forward(ahead)

    behind = 50 - ahead

    if behind:
        heading -= 180

        if heading != yertle.heading():
            yertle.setheading(heading)

        yertle.forward(behind)

    if yertle.heading() != 0:
        yertle.setheading(0)

def k1():
    screen.onkey(None, "Up")
    move_turtle(HEIGHT/2 - yertle.ycor(), 0)
    screen.onkey(k1, "Up")

def k2():
    screen.onkey(None, "Left")
    move_turtle(yertle.xcor() + WIDTH/2, 270)
    screen.onkey(k2, "Left")

def k3():
    screen.onkey(None, "Right")
    move_turtle(WIDTH/2 - yertle.xcor(), 90)
    screen.onkey(k3, "Right")

def k4():
    screen.onkey(None, "Down")
    move_turtle(HEIGHT/2 + yertle.ycor(), 180)
    screen.onkey(k4, "Down")

screen = Screen()
screen.mode('logo')  # since 'up' is crucial, make it 0 degrees

yertle = Turtle()
yertle.penup()

border = Turtle(visible=False)
border.speed("fastest")  # because I have no patience
border.pensize(3)
border.penup()
border.setposition(-WIDTH/2, -HEIGHT/2)
border.pendown()

for _ in range(2):
    border.forward(HEIGHT)
    border.right(90)
    border.forward(WIDTH)
    border.right(90)

screen.onkey(k1, "Up")
screen.onkey(k2, "Left")
screen.onkey(k3, "Right")
screen.onkey(k4, "Down")

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```