# How do I change the Hitbox size of a turtle in python turtle graphics?

Tags: python, collision, turtle-graphics

I dont know how to change the size of a turtle hitbox in python turtle graphics

I haven't tried anything yet because I'm new, and know very little about this. I've tried googling it, though, but nothing popped up.

```
from turtle import *
import turtle
from random import randint
import time

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(1920, 1080)
player = turtle.Turtle()
```

I want to add a button that you have to click to start right here

The game starts right here :

```
wn = turtle.Screen()

last_pressed = 'up'

def setup(col, x, y, w, s, shape):

  player.penup()
  player.up()
  player.goto(x,y)
  player.width(w)
  player.turtlesize(s)
  player.color(col)
  player.lt(90)
  player.down()
  wn.onkey(up, "s")
  wn.onkey(left, "d")
  wn.onkey(right, "a")
  wn.onkey(back, "w")
  wn.onkey(quitTurtles, "Escape")
  wn.listen()
  wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but this might work in your situation.
[Detecting collision in Python turtle game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461566/detecting-collision-in-python-turtle-game)
This is a thread on collision detection between objects and with some tweaking of numbers you could increase the hitbox of the turtle using the `abs()` function

Answer (score 0):

```
I dont know how to change the size of a turtle hitbox in python turtle graphics
```

What do you mean by "hitbox"?  I'm not sure what you mean by that (and neither does Google, apparently).

Do you mean that you want a rectangular button to click on?  If that's the case, you could use the `tkinter` module together with the `turtle` module to create a button to click.  (But be aware that it's not always easy to get the `tkinter` and `turtle` modules to work together to do what you want.)

If you want a button to click on, but don't need a Tkinter button, you could just try creating a new turtle in the shape of a rectangle that intercepts mouse clicks with `onclick()`.  You can see an example of this if you run:

```
 python3 -m turtledemo
```

and select `Examples` >> `colormixer` from the main menubar.

Or, if by "hitbox" you mean how to detect when one turtle has *intercepted* another turtle (as in, one has come close enough to the other to be considered a "hit"), I suggest querying each turtle's location, then using the Pythagorean Theorem to calculate the distance from each other.  If this distance is within a predetermined threshold, consider the hitbox as being "hit."

You can see an example of this by typing:

```
python3 -m turtle
```

(Pay attention to the yellow turtle as he tries to catch up to the other turtle.)

I apologize if this answer isn't quite what you're looking for, but I'm just not sure what you mean by "hitbox."  Maybe you could clarify?

Comment: When I say hitbox, I mean the part of the turtle that interacts with things.An example would be this
https://www.gamecrate.com/sites/default/files/smash-bros-hitbox-meme.jpg

The boxes are the hitboxes, which are the parts to interact with. The other things are just the image of the character

Comment: As far as I know, python turtles don't have hitboxes.  In the few programs I've seen where a turtle needs to interact with an object (such as in `python -m turtle`), the location of the turtle is compared to the location of the object being interacted with.  You can see how `python -m turtle` does this by searching the code for the word `CAUGHT` (you can find the path of the proper code file by typing `python -c "help('turtle')"` and scrolling down to the very bottom; there you'll see the turtle module's path).  Check out this code and maybe you'll get an idea of how to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this question today (2 years too late i know), and was having a similar problem / question.

What I ended up doing was running 3 distance checks (as i had increased my object size by 3) which differed along the x-axis (width). So it would check the distance between the ball(turtle) and the paddle (any 3 points and if it was shorter than X it would trigger the collision mechanic.

so it was something like :
check the ball class' ball object, and see how far away it is from the paddle,
and if its either in the center, or 30 pixels to the left or right of the center then hit.

```
if 
ball.ball.distance(pad.paddle(), pad.paddle.ycor()) < 30 or
ball.ball.distance(pad.paddle.xcor() - 30, pad.paddle.ycor()) < 30 or
ball.ball.distance(pad.paddle.xcor() + 30, pad.paddle.ycor()) < 30
```