# How do I make my game reset when my turtle hits an sprite?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

The title explains what I want to do with this program, when my turtle hits a circle, the game resets/ends

Here is the code for the spaceship (your character):

```
move = turtle.Turtle()

showturtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
move.setposition(-500,0)
move.pencolor('cyan')
move.fillcolor("blue")
move.penup()
move.speed()
move.shapesize(3,3,3)



turtle.fillcolor("blue")
turtle.shapesize(3,3,3)
outline = ['white', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow', 'orange']
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black']


def up():
   move.forward(25)

def down():
   move.backward(15)

def left():
    move.left(30)


def right():
    move.right(30)
 


def clickleft(x,y):
    move.fillcolor(random.choice(colors))

def clickright(x,y):
    move.pencolor(random.choice(outline))


    
turtle.listen()

turtle.onscreenclick(clickleft, 1)
turtle.onscreenclick(clickright, 3)

turtle.onkey(up, 'Up')
turtle.onkey(down, 'Down')
turtle.onkey(left, 'Left')
turtle.onkey(right, 'Right')
```

And here is the asteroid(sprite that when move hits, the game resets):

```
asteroid_prototype = Turtle()
asteroid_prototype.hideturtle()
asteroid_prototype.color('grey')
asteroid_prototype.shape('circle')
asteroid_prototype.shapesize(ASTEROID_RADIUS / CURSOR_SIZE)
asteroid_prototype.speed('fastest')  # because 15 isn't a valid argument
asteroid_prototype.penup()

asteroids = []

for _ in range(NUMBER_ASTEROIDS):
    asteroid = asteroid_prototype.clone()
    asteroid.setposition( \
        randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - WIDTH, WIDTH - ASTEROID_RADIUS), \
        randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - HEIGHT, HEIGHT - ASTEROID_RADIUS) \
    )

    while any(map((lambda a: lambda b: a.distance(b) < ASTEROID_RADIUS)(asteroid), asteroids)):
        asteroid.setposition( \
            randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - WIDTH, WIDTH - ASTEROID_RADIUS), \
            randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - HEIGHT, HEIGHT - ASTEROID_RADIUS) \
        )

    asteroid.showturtle()
    asteroids.append(asteroid)
```

I need it so if move hits asteroid_prototype, the game resets or at least ends.
Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461566/detecting-collision-in-python-turtle-game

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a function for moving everything to its start position(I've named it startPos). I would put all the positions of the turtles, reset any score counts to 0, and empty any lists of enemies etc inside this function. Then, call it when asteroid_prototype and your turtle are in the same position. For example, have inside your main loop

```
for i in range(asteroids):
    if i.xcor == turtle.xcor and i.ycor == turtle.ycor:
        startPos()
```

You can always change the parameters slightly so that they don't have to be in exactly the same position `if i.xcor > turtle.xcor - 5 and i.xcor < turtle.xcor + 5 and i.ycor > turtle.ycor - 5 and i.ycor < turtle.ycor + 5`, or something like that. You may want to make the parameters the size of the turtle/asteroid radius (I've chosen 5 as an arbitrary number).

I hope this helps and is written clearly enough.