# How do I implement collision detection with Python Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Good afternoon
I need my program to reset when my python turtle hits a circle. There are 53 circles.
Here is the turtle.

```
move = turtle.Turtle()
move.penup()
showturtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
move.setposition(-500,0)
move.pencolor('cyan')
move.fillcolor("blue")
move.pos()
move.speed()
move.shapesize(3,3,3)



turtle.fillcolor("blue")
turtle.shapesize(3,3,3)
outline = ['white', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow', 'orange','black','gray']
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black','gray']
size = ['4,4,4', '2,2,2']
bg = ['blue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black', 'gray']
def up():
   move.forward(25)

def down():
   move.backward(15)

def left():
    move.left(30)


def right():
    move.right(30)

def b():
   turtle.bgcolor(random.choice(bg))


 


def clickleft(x,y):
    move.fillcolor(random.choice(colors))

def clickright(x,y):
    move.pencolor(random.choice(outline))


    
turtle.listen()

turtle.onscreenclick(clickleft, 1)
turtle.onscreenclick(clickright, 3)

turtle.onkey(up, 'Up')
turtle.onkey(down, 'Down')
turtle.onkey(left, 'Left')
turtle.onkey(right, 'Right')
turtle.onkey(b, 'b')
```

And here is the code for all the asteroids. They have to be this size and shape unless there's another way to make sure the circles can't overlap

```
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 400, 400
ASTEROID_RADIUS = 53
NUMBER_ASTEROIDS = 53
CURSOR_SIZE = 20


asteroid = Turtle()

if move.distance(asteroid)<5:
    move.goto(0,0)

asteroid_prototype = Turtle()
asteroid_prototype.hideturtle()
asteroid_prototype.color('grey')
asteroid_prototype.shape('circle')
asteroid_prototype.shapesize(ASTEROID_RADIUS / CURSOR_SIZE)
asteroid_prototype.speed('fastest')  # because 15 isn't a valid argument
asteroid_prototype.penup()

asteroids = []

for _ in range(NUMBER_ASTEROIDS):
    asteroid = asteroid_prototype.clone()
    asteroid.setposition( \
        randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - WIDTH, WIDTH - ASTEROID_RADIUS), \
        randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - HEIGHT, HEIGHT - ASTEROID_RADIUS) \
    )

    while any(map((lambda a: lambda b: a.distance(b) < ASTEROID_RADIUS)(asteroid), asteroids)):
        asteroid.setposition( \
            randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - WIDTH, WIDTH - ASTEROID_RADIUS), \
            randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - HEIGHT, HEIGHT - ASTEROID_RADIUS) \
         )
   

    asteroid.showturtle()
    asteroids.append(asteroid)
```

The code has to be like this so the circles don't overlap
Thank you in advance

Comment: As @JLeno46 already said either change where you are posting or add an appropriate title that goes with what you are asking.

Comment: Read "How to ask a good question" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask start with some basic google searches for "Python turtle collision" and try and implement some of the suggestions you find there.  your code as it is does not make any attempt to solve the problem you say that you have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting collision in Python turtle game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461566/detecting-collision-in-python-turtle-game)

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a function that will reset the player's position and the positions of all the asteroids.
2. Add a while loop to constantly check to see if the player collides with any of the asteroids.
3. When detected a collision, call the `reset` function.

```
def reset(asteroids):
    move.setposition(-500,0)
    for asteroid in asteroids:
        asteroid.goto(1000, 1000)
    asteroids2 = []
    for asteroid in asteroids:
        asteroid.setposition( \
            randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - WIDTH, WIDTH - ASTEROID_RADIUS), \
            randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - HEIGHT, HEIGHT - ASTEROID_RADIUS) \
        )

        while any(map((lambda a: lambda b: a.distance(b) < ASTEROID_RADIUS)(asteroid), asteroids2)):
            asteroid.setposition( \
                randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - WIDTH, WIDTH - ASTEROID_RADIUS), \
                randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - HEIGHT, HEIGHT - ASTEROID_RADIUS) \
             )
       
        asteroid.showturtle()
        asteroids2.append(asteroid)
    return asteroids2

turtle.listen()

turtle.onscreenclick(clickleft, 1)
turtle.onscreenclick(clickright, 3)

turtle.onkey(up, 'Up')
turtle.onkey(down, 'Down')
turtle.onkey(left, 'Left')
turtle.onkey(right, 'Right')
turtle.onkey(b, 'b')
while True:
    if any(move.distance(asteroid) < 37 for asteroid in asteroids):
        asteroids = reset(asteroids)
    update()
```