# Trying to calculate if a rectangle is gonna hit another rectangle or not when one of them is moving using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rectangles, calculation, python-turtle

I have two rectangles. One's position is random and other one has a specific starting position.
The random one just stands there but the other one is moving to the right (it can go to other rotations too: it does not have to go to the right) and I am trying to calculate and write to the command window if the moving one is going to hit the random not moving one or not. I am using latest python version and turtle library.

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: @Axe319 I just don't know how to calculate and write to the command window

Comment: Something like this? [Detecting collision in Python turtle game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461566/detecting-collision-in-python-turtle-game)

Comment: @Axe319 yeah I needed the collision stuff thanks for answering