# Turtle Collision Python

Tags: python, window, collision-detection, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am creating a snake game and I want an action to happen if I touch another turtle on my screen?

```
fruit = turtle.Turtle()
fruit.penup()
fruit.size = 45
fruit.color("Black")
fruit.shape("circle")
fruit.goto(randint(-180,0),randint(0,180))
```

That is the fruit code so you know what I have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting collision in Python turtle game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461566/detecting-collision-in-python-turtle-game)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the Turtle package doesn't have a built-in collision mechanism, so you will have to define what a collision is, and repeatedly check for a collision yourself.

---

You can define a "collision" checking function using whatever definiton of collision you want.

For example if the distance between the centers of the two fruits is less than the combined radii of the turtles, that means the edges of the circles are overlapping. (For more complex shape a custom box or shape could be used to detect collisions)

Turtles' [shapesize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.shapesize) gives a multiplier on the default turtle size of 20, which we half to get the radius:

```py
def is_collided(a, b):
  distance = b.distance(a.pos())
  radius_a = a.shapesize()[0] * 10 
  radius_b = b.shapesize()[0] * 10
  return radius_a + radius_b >= distance
```

---

You can then define a list of different turtles, and loop through them to check whether any of them have collided with your fruit, and print if so:

```py
other_turtles = [turtle1, turtle2, turtle3]

for t in other_turtles:
    if is_collided(fruit, t):
        # can define other actions here
        print(f'collision between fruit and {t}')
```

---

If you just copy those two snippets directly below your sample code, and replace `turtle1, turtle2` with the names of your other turtles, it should work.

---

*You can also see this in action with different fruits [here](https://replit.com/@LukeStorry/67997540#main.py).*

Comment: This equation `a.shapesize()[0] + b.shapesize()[0]) * 10` is the combined *radii* of the two turtles (20), not combilned *sizes* (40).  And you pulled `10` out of a hat -- document or declare it.  Finally, this `b.distance(a.pos())` can be expressed `b.distance(a)`.

Comment: Can you please put this answer in my code I have done to help u because I don't get this. I tried it but it ain't work

Comment: @cdlane apologies for not documenting that, was only meant to be a rough example.

Comment: @DhruvCoder I've simplified the answer a bit so you should be able to copy those two snippets of code into your file. The linked repl is still the full example for reference.

Comment: Please note that  I have one fruit.

Comment: @LukeStorry I tried this but when I collided I started to move the fruit not the player and it says there was a collision at the start of the game

Comment: Well I don't know what the game is, or what the player is, so can't really help with that. Maybe post another question? Here I've given you code to define and check for a collision between two turtles, as you asked, you'll have to give more context if you want to be shown how to connect that into the larger game you're creating.

Comment: I fixed it. I used something else :D