# How do you check if a turtle is touching another turtle in Python turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to make it so that when the space bar is clicked, it runs the function `shoot()`. It works, but whenever you hit the target, it doesn't do what the `if` statement says in the `shoot()` function, and updates the score wrongly. The output usually takes away a point from score instead of adding 1 to score as expected. I think the values are wrong but I do not know what to set them as. I have even tried to make another turtle to measure values to try by trial and error.

The code is as shown below:

```
import random
import turtle
import time

# variables
score = 0

# setup screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
wn.title('Archery Game')
wn.tracer(0)

bg = turtle.Turtle()
bg.speed(0)
bg.hideturtle()
bg.penup()
bg.goto(-300, 300)

def sky():
    bg.color('#80bfff')
    bg.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        bg.forward(600)
        bg.right(90)
        bg.forward(375)
        bg.right(90)
    bg.end_fill()

gr = turtle.Turtle()
gr.speed(0)
gr.hideturtle()
gr.penup()
gr.goto(-300, -75)

# target
# outer circle
outer = turtle.Turtle()
outer.speed(0)
outer.penup()
outer.goto(0, 0)
outer.shape('circle')
outer.color('blue')
outer.shapesize(12, 12, 12)

# middle circle
middle = turtle.Turtle()
middle.speed(0)
middle.penup()
middle.goto(0, 0)
middle.shape('circle')
middle.color('red')
middle.shapesize(8, 8, 8)

# inner circle
inner = turtle.Turtle()
inner.speed(0)
inner.penup()
inner.goto(0, 0)
inner.shape('circle')
inner.color('yellow')
inner.shapesize(4, 4, 4)

# random position
#x = random.randint(-150, 150)
#y = random.randint(-150, 150)

# dart
dart = turtle.Turtle()
dart.speed(0)
dart.penup()
dart.shape('circle')
dart.color('white')
dart.goto(0, 0)

def grass():
    gr.color('#90E36F')
    gr.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        gr.forward(600)
        gr.right(90)
        gr.forward(225)
        gr.right(90)
    gr.end_fill()

def shoot():
    global score
    # get dart position
    x = dart.xcor()
    y = dart.ycor()
    # check if dart is in target
    if dart.distance(outer) < 40:
        score += 1
        print('Score: {}'.format(score))
        # move dart to random position
        dart.goto(random.randint(-150, 150), random.randint(-150, 150))
    elif dart.distance(middle) < 80 and dart.distance(outer) < 120:
        score += 2
        print('Score: {}'.format(score))
        # move dart to random position
        dart.goto(random.randint(-150, 150), random.randint(-150, 150))
    elif dart.distance(inner) < 40 and dart.distance(middle) < 80:
        score += 3
        print('Score: {}'.format(score))
        # move dart to random position
        dart.goto(random.randint(-150, 150), random.randint(-150, 150))
    else:
        score -= 1
        print('Score: {}'.format(score))
        # move dart to random position
        dart.goto(random.randint(-150, 150), random.randint(-150, 150))
```

I don't get an error but the code doesn't display what I want, and I have no idea on how to fix it.

I tried to measure points in the screen with a new turtle to try and fix the mishap by trial and error. In the code, I am trying to give the player +1 score if they hit the blue outer ring of the target, +2 score if they hit the red middle ring and +3 score if they hit the yellow inner ring. BUT if they do not hit any ring and hit outside of the target, they will lose -1 score. If there is a command I didn't know that I can use to check if the dart is touching the layers of the target, it would help significantly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting collision in Python turtle game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461566/detecting-collision-in-python-turtle-game)

Answer (score 0):

Your code as posted is incomplete so I can't run it and give a definitive answer.  But looking at your `shoot()` code, I think you've made an incorrect assumption:

```
if dart.distance(outer) < 40:
    ...
elif dart.distance(middle) < 80 and dart.distance(outer) < 120:
    ...
elif dart.distance(inner) < 40 and dart.distance(middle) < 80:
    ...
```

Since your three circular turtles are *concentric*, the distance of the dart to *any* of them, is always the same.  Distance is measured to the center point of the circle and all share the same center point.

I would have expected something more like the following:

```
if dart.distance(inner) < 40:
    score += 3
    ...
elif dart.distance(middle) < 80:
    score += 2
    ...
elif dart.distance(outer) < 120:
    score += 1
    ...
```